# Getting error when using facebook authentication in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, curl, facebook-oauth

I am using [Facebook-Oauth](https://github.com/brennannovak/codeigniter-facebook-oauth). I am using windows 7 and i am trying to run it in my localserver. I am setting site-url :http://www.domain.com and canvas url : http://www.domain.com/ . I didn't make change any other change in settings in the facebook developer site.But whenever i am trying to run it in my localhost i am getting this error :

```
1.Message: Use of undefined constant CURLPROXY_HTTP - assumed 'CURLPROXY_HTTP'
2.Message: Use of undefined constant CURLAUTH_BASIC - assumed 'CURLAUTH_BASIC'
```

Both in

```
Filename: core/Loader.php

Line Number: 956
```

I have set the app id and app secrect key in the config file.

```
$config['facebook_app_id']          = '424824207643973';
$config['facebook_api_key']             = '424824207643973';
$config['facebook_secret_key']          = 'my-app-secretkey';
```

Comment: Ensure you actually have PHP pointed at CURL. Windows doesn't include curl by default and so, usually, special dlls have to be downloaded and used in order to activate its functionality. Have you gotten curl to work before? Once you have the dlls, make sure php.ini has been modified to include the extensions.

Comment: No i haven't any experience with CURL. Before didn't try to run any CURL project.

Comment: Here are the CURL docs, there is a tiny section on using this on Windows. My advice to you is to install llamp on a Linux box and use that instead ;)    http://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.installation.php

Comment: Got the error solved but now another problem. : When i click the login  button i am not able to login or see any other message. Before clicking the button my link is :http://localhost:81/codeigniter-facebook-oauth-master/fboauth/   and after clicking it my link becomes : http://localhost:81/codeigniter-facebook-oauth-master/fboauth/%3C?=%20$data['auth_url']%20?%3E   and getting "Access forbidden!"

Comment: You have some sort of syntax error somewhere that is appending some of your PHP to the end of the URL. Can you modify your original code? If you have CLI PHP enabled/installed you can do: php -l filename.php from the command line to go ahead and check.

Answer (score 1):

cURL is most likely not installed correctly or linked up to PHP. Windows does not come with cURL installed (another reason to switch to a *nix based system! but I digress) so you'll need the appropriate dll files to enable it, then link those in via your php.ini file.

With regards to your current error, please check for syntax errors and leave a comment on this answer and update your provided source, and I'll modify.